# How come using multiprocessing isn't any faster? am i doing it wrong?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I made a python script to solve a complex math problem and write the result to a text file. but it takes a long time so I wanted to make it utilize more of my i7-7700K because it only uses 18%. so I tried using multiprocessing. but its not faster. Am I doing it wrong? 
(side note) when I run it with multiprocessing the text file is blank when it finishes. and I don't know why.

I watched a bunch of youtube videos on how to use multiprocessing.

```
import time
import multiprocessing



solve = open("solve.txt", "w")

def per1(n, steps=0):

    if steps == 0:
        print(n)

    if len(str(n))==1:
        print("Total steps " + str(steps))
        return "Done"

    steps += 1

    digits = [int(i) for i in str (n)]

    result = 1

    for j in digits:
        result *= j

    # print(result)

    per1(result, steps)

    S = 2

    solve = open("solve.txt", "r")
    if 'steps 1' in open('solve.txt').read():
        S = 2

    if 'steps 2' in open('solve.txt').read():
        S = 3

    if 'steps 3' in open('solve.txt').read():
        S = 4

    if 'steps 4' in open('solve.txt').read():
        S = 5

    if 'steps 5' in open('solve.txt').read():
        S = 6

    if 'steps 6' in open('solve.txt').read():
        S = 7

    if 'steps 7' in open('solve.txt').read():
        S = 8

    if steps == S:
        solve = open("solve.txt", "a")
        solve.write("# steps ")
        solve.write(str(steps))
        solve.write("\n")
        solve.write("x = ")
        solve.write(str(x))
        # solve.write(" results ")
        # solve.write(str(result))
        solve.write("\n")

x = 1
y = 2

# with multiprocessing

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while x <= 2000:
    # while x <= 277777788888899:
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=per1(x)) #works ish
        # p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=per1, args=(x,)) #does not work
        print("P1")
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=per1(y)) #works ish
        # p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=per1, args=(y,)) #does not work
        print("P2")
        # per1(x)
        x += 2
        y += 2

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()


# normal way

# while x <= 2000:
# # while x <= 277777788888899:
#     per1(x)
#     x += 1


print("My program took", time.time() - start_time, "to run")
solve = open("solve.txt", "a")
solve.write(str(time.time() - start_time))

solve.close()
```

I split it into 2 processes one tests the odd numbers the other tests even numbers, and it works but it's not any faster than the normal way.
I was expecting it to go twice as fast with multiprocessing.

Comment: What is `per1`?

Comment: I don't see you writing to a file anywhere in this code. Please add a minimal, complete and verifiable example

Comment: I can see why this wouldn't be faster, if each run of per1() doesn't take long to run.  Python needs to spend extra work to get code running in a separate process. That work could take longer than the actual task, slowing everything down. - The way you really want to do this is to be able to dispatch to each process just once.  Have the loop be inside each of the processes, rather than outside in the main program.  I expect that if you did this, you'd see a significant advantage. - so obviously, you'd dispatch two processes, passing in even vs odd as a parameter

Comment: Another note, you are also only starting the processes when x and y are both 2000, not anywhere in-between. I'm guessing ideally you would want per1 to be executing this while loop

Comment: where is y defined?  I think you want just x, and you want to pass x and x+1 to the two processes

Comment: @Nightshade, I don't see what you're saying.  x is never initialized, but it grows by 2 each time around, and a process gets dispatched each time, right?

Comment: @suicidalteddy 
per1 is the function that does the math to solve the math problem.

Comment: @NightShade 
  while x <= 2000:
wile x is less than or = to 2000
so it will run until it hits 2000

Comment: @Steve What I am saying is that (assuming x and y are defined first) you are creating an instance of the process each time through the loop but you are not calling .start() on this instance. .start() in this case only gets called when the exit condition of the loop is satisfied (x = 2000), so it doesn't matter if x is say, 100, these processes will not run (check indentation). edit: just checked code, will run when x = 2001, y = 2002

Comment: Doh!...I'm blind!  You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling your function in place and giving the result to the multiprocessing. You must hand in the function as a callable and the arguments separately:

```
multiprocessing.Process(target=per1, args=(x,))
```

Comment: Ha!  Good catch.  I missed that. So then what is the subprocess even doing?  Note that it's possible that per1() is returning a function pointer.  We can't know since we don't have it's implementation.  But I assume as you do, that per1() is doing the actual work.

Comment: like this?:
```
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=per1, args=(x,))           
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=per1, args=(y,))

```
because that doesn't work at all.

Comment: That explains a lot: your code has so much file I/O in it that it will substantially slow down the execution.

Comment: @KlausD. I wanted it to write the answers to the text file. that's kinda the point of it. it only writes when it finds an answer.

Comment: Your program spents most of its time waiting for I/O to complete without using the CPU intensively. Spreading it over multiple processes and therefore CPUs will not make it faster since they are all waiting for I/O. Optimize your code to stop reading in several times and write in one shot.

Comment: Write in one shot wouldn't work if it ran infinity. Because it would never end.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly will note some insight into what your maths problem would be helpful to give some optimizations which may otherwise speed up the execution. On brief look I can determine there are a few things including:

- you check if `"steps 1"` is written in solve.txt, this can never be the case since S is at least 2 (or more) and you check if `steps == S`
- to access step N you must have visited all step 2 through to step N-1 before. This means it is valid to write something like the code below. This will also save a lot of un-necessary checking (perhaps less can be done knowing what the problem is, or saving time checking in memory):

```
# since once 'S' isn't found, n >= S will not be in solve.txt
S = 2
while ("steps " + str(S)) in open('solve.txt').read() and S < 8:
    S += 1
```

- solve.txt is opened at least 2 times during the program, maybe more depending how many calls in the stack there are to per1
- Klaus D has shown the right way to call the function but also note you only call `.start()` when `x = 2001`, and `y = 2002`. This immediately causes `result` to become 0, and hence no results are saved (as length of 0 is 1), returning without any IO. You would be looking to do something like this (untested):

```
    def driver(start, end, step):
        for i in range(start, end+1, step):
            per1(i)

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=driver, args=(1, 2000, 2))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=driver, args=(0, 2000, 2))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

- Also note a multiprocess is expensive to start, but is then efficient once it has started, so should only be used if you know your program will take a long time to run for each process. Hope this helps :)